# file with zero data

Tags: java, android

my adroid app starts camera, makes picture and then it should save it to /apptest_files. Picture from camera is saved in camera gallery, image in /apptest_files is created but with 0 bytes (it is not "copied" from source file). I have no idea why this happens. Any idea please?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.apptest.legs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.example.apptest.SPref;
import com.example.apptest.service.out.UploaderFileService.MyHttpClient;
import com.example.apptest.singleton.DefaultUser;
import com.example.apptest.utils.UtilsServer;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class ImageHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String TAG = ImageHolderFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private boolean isLoading;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String imageName;

    private interface Arguments {
        String IMAGE_NAME = "IMAGE_NAME";
    }

    public interface OnImageStateChangeCallbacks {
        public void onImageStateChange(boolean isLoading, Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            getImage();
        }
    };
    public static ImageHolderFragment getHolder(FragmentActivity activity,
            String imageName) {
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        ImageHolderFragment f = (ImageHolderFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if (f == null) {
            f = new ImageHolderFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(Arguments.IMAGE_NAME, imageName);
            f.setArguments(b);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(f, TAG).commit();
        }
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        imageName = getArguments().getString(Arguments.IMAGE_NAME);
        bitmap = null;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageName)) {
            isLoading = false;
            return;
        } else {
            isLoading = true;
        }

        boolean success = tryOffline();
        if (success) {
            getImage();
        } else {
            new BackgroundDownloader().start();
        }
    }

    private boolean tryOffline() {
        try {
            File imageFile = getFile();
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                int width = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
                int height = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi;
                int size;
                if (width < height) {
                    size = height;
                } else {
                    size = width;
                }
                size *=2;
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
                int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
                int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

                // Determine how much to scale down the image
                int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / size, photoH / size);

                // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bmOptions);

                isLoading = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        bitmap = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void getImage() {
        try {
            ((OnImageStateChangeCallbacks) getActivity()).onImageStateChange(
                    isLoading, bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private File getFile() {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/apptest_files");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        File outFile = new File(directory.getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/" + imageName);
        return outFile;
    }

    private class BackgroundDownloader extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                File imageFile = getFile();
                if(imageFile.exists()){
                    imageFile.delete();
                }
                imageFile.createNewFile();
                SPref sPref = SPref.getInstance(getActivity());
                DefaultUser defaultUser = sPref.getDefaultUser();
                String serverUrl = UtilsServer.getServerID(defaultUser)
                        + "file_out/";

                URI url = URI.create(serverUrl);
                HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);

                DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float size;
                if (metrics.xdpi < metrics.ydpi) {
                    size = metrics.ydpi;
                } else {
                    size = metrics.xdpi;
                }
                size *=3;
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA_NAME",
                        imageName));
                postParameters
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA_TYPE", "IMAGE"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA_NAME",
                        imageName));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RESIZE", "1"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WIDTH", String
                        .valueOf((int) size)));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("HEIGHT", String
                        .valueOf((int) size)));

                p.setHeader("Cookie", "AUTH=" + defaultUser.ID);

                p.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

                HttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient(getActivity());
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(p);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    bitmap = null;
                } else {
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[124];
                    int bufferSize = 0;
                    while ((bufferSize = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    is.close();

                    //

                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                            imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                bitmap = null;

            }
            isLoading = false;
            Message msg = new Message();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A ridiculous amount of code you posted.

Comment: why? I am not experienced app dev, so if any other code helps, please, tell me.